# Looping through lines in several files (bash)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to create a script that goes line by line in a file, extracts the last word in each sentence and performs another script I created (which works, called intermediate) and prints all of that as separate lines.

For some reason I get an endless loop.

```
function find_id {
  next_file="${*:2}"
  temp_file="`echo $next_file | cut -d"." -f1`"
  if [[ $temp_file != station ]]; then
      while read line; do
          if [[ -f "${temp_file}.station" ]]; then
              train_col=$((${#line[*]}-1))
              $train_id=`echo ${line[${train_col}]}`
              echo -n "`intermediate $train_id`"
          fi
      done < ${temp_file}.station
      next_file="`echo $next_file | cut -d"." -f2- | cut -d" " -f2-`"
      temp_file="`echo $next_file | cut -d"." -f1`"
      echo "`find_id $1 $next_file`"
  fi

}

file_list= `ls *.station``
echo "`find_id $1 $file_list``" | sort -n | cut -d" " -f2- | uniq
```

I'm not allowed to use awk or sed.

Answer (score 2):

With the activity you are doing as explained in your question seems you only need an `awk` for those all things instead.

```
awk '$NF' infile*.txt > outfile.txt
```

The `$NF` is referring to the last word (means a word with whitespaces around) in each line in `awk`.

While the above `awk` solution is there, you can use can read the lines to an array and print last element of that array with negative index (bash 4.3 and above).

```
arrayedline=( $line ) 
printf "%s\n", "${arrayedline[@]-1}"
```

In older version of `bash` your can use expression in index `arrayedline[${#arrayedline[@]-1}]`, which with substring one from the length of array `${#arrayedline[@]}` we can get last element of that.

```
arrayedline=( $line )
printf "%s\n", "${arrayedline[${#arrayedline[@]}-1]}"
```

Or you can even use as follows :

```
printf "%s\n", "${arrayedline[@]:(-1)}"  #or
printf "%s\n", "${arrayedlne[@]: -1}"
```

Now that in `bash` array index is starting from `0`.

Comment: And if I have to work around not being able to use awk or $NF?

Comment: @evgniytayarov What Unix without `awk` are you using?

Comment: @evgniytayarov Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with the additional requirement that you cannot use `sed` either:

```
for i in `split -n 1 fn* --filter='cat | rev | cut -f 1 -d 'f' | rev'`; do ./yourscript.sh $i; done
```

Explanation of why it works:

`split` splits the files whose filename starts with `fn` into lines, and processes `cat | rev | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | rev` on each line.

`cat` echoes that line, `rev` reverses it, `cut` separates it into words delimited by `' '` and outputs the first word of the reversed string, `rev` reverses it back; you get the last word of your line.

Then the `for...do...done` executes your script on that word.